# React axios put в определенное место массива

Tags: reactjs, requests, axios, put

На сайте есть создание блока, а есть дублирование. При дублировании нужно отправлять на сервер дублированный объект после индекса дублированного.

То есть, есть 10 элементов. Мы дублируем 5-й и наш дублированный объект становится не 11-м, а 6-м. Я в заблуждении, как это можно реализовать.  В голову приходит только мысль - скопировать весь объект с сервера в переменную, очистить данные на сервере, изменить объект и залить заново - этот метод крайне плох, поэтому спрашиваю тут.

Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Как это все хранится на сервере? В каком виде? Что за база?

Comment: @bonusrk База на питоне написана, я не особо в курсе. на скрине видно остальное - http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2020/01/13/0014/0699/975547/47/9fde7522d1.jpg

Comment: На скрине мы видим массив объектов. Если не особо в курсе, что на сервере, но в курсе то для "дублирования элемента" нужно отправить дублированный элемент и индекс дублированного тогда в чем проблема отправить это? Зачем вся эта пляска с переменными, сохранения и, очистка и и вот этим всем? ...база на питоне....

Comment: @bonusrk axios.put отправляет 1 объект на сервер и кладет его в самый конец. Как мне его положить не в самый конец? Хорошо, раз так очевидно, как мне указать индекс, куда класть новый объект при вызове axios.put?

Comment: Зависит от того как это принимает  и обрабатывает бэкенд. Если он поддерживает возможность вставки на некий индекс, лучшее место где можно это узнать - документация этого бэкенда

Comment: @bonusrk Спасибо, узнаю сейчас